# Fastest way to filter and sort Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large Nx2 numpy array called `points` of `[x, y]` coordinates and I want to filter it by Euclidean distance and then sort it by shortest distance. Each point in the array will be tested against another given point, call it `p1`, and I only want the `[x, y]` coordinates within a given distance `rad` to `p1`. I then want to sort the filtered `points` by the distance to `p1`, from shortest to longest. Knowing the distance is not necessary, only that the order of `points` by the end follows this rule. Is there a way fast way to do this without any for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import numpy as np

distances = np.linalg.norm(points - p1, axis=-1)

new_points = points[distances < rad]
new_distances = distances[distances < rad]

new_distances = np.expand_dims(new_distances, axis=-1)

new_points_with_new_distances = np.hstack((new_points, new_distances))

indices=np.argsort(new_points_with_new_distances[:,-1])

sorted_new_points_with_new_distances = new_points_with_new_distances[indices]

sorted_new_points = sorted_new_points_with_new_distances[:,:-1]
```